# TalkBack should read Heading

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

All headers in the app should have the accessibility trait (heading), which should be read aloud by TalkBack. For example, `CardView` title should be read as **"My Title Heading"**
I implemented using `setContentDescription` but is there any other method to announce Headings like in iOs there is accessibilty traits.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642769/navigate-between-headings-with-swipe-while-using-talkback) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an android developer but found java.lang.Object > android.R.styleable which has a [`View_accessibilityHeading`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#View_accessibilityHeading) property.  What you're looking for is a way to specify the **role** of the object so that you can satisfy [WCAG 4.1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/ensure-compat-rsv.html).  There are many types of roles. See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions for a list of roles available for HTML developers.  You should have a similar list of roles for Android.