# Navigate between headings with swipe while using talkback

Tags: android, screen-readers, talkback, accessibility

Android 9 has introduced `accessibilityHeading` tag, which can be used by talkback to announce the Headings.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#a11y

Look for `Heading-based navigation`

In my app I have multiple Textviews in my activity with some Headings

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:accessibilityHeading="true"
            android:text="Accessibility Heading 1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="Message"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
```

But when I run the app, headings are treated as normal textviews only and no special treatment is given by `Talkback`.

I can swipe left to navigate through all elements. 
There is option to swipe up to change mode for talkback announcements. e.g `Default`, `Links`, `Controls`, `Headings` etc.

When chosen `Headings`, I expect talkback to announce only headings and to jump from one heading to another but it stays at the same place even after `Swipe Left` or `Swipe Right` gesture.

Comment: any update on this. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: It works exactly how you said it should work on my device (Mi Mix 2)

Answer (score 3):

Set both `accessibilityHeading` and `focusableInTouchMode` to `true`. Then, after setting the navigation mode to `Headers` (you can do this via the `up down` gesture), swiping `up` or `down` navigates you though the headers. Swiping `right` and `left` will still allow you to navigate through single items.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. 
In my particular situation it was fixed when I set `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to false in the parent view, and true in the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried, it work here as expected.
Talkback properly announces textviews as headings and in heading mode I can navigate to them as well.
Please ensure that you are using the latest version of Talkback.
This is quite an old question so may be you may have got the solution since then